# How to handle with two Scanners which gets same file

Tags: java

I have a problem in handling two concurrent `Scanner` objects.

One scanner is used to determine the number of lines in the file and the other scanner is used to fetch the lines and add it to an array.

The reason is becasue to declare an array we need the size of an array, which is why I'm using the first scanner.

I'm not getting any errors, just a blank console.

```java
File file = new File("E:\\"+fileName);
Scanner inputSize = new Scanner(file);
inputSize.next();
int size = 0;
while(inputSize.hasNext()) {
    size = size + 1;
}
inputSize.close();
Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
PermissionSetTabSetting[] record = new PermissionSetTabSetting[size];
PermissionSetTabSetting tabSetting;
int count = 0;
inputStream.next();
System.out.println(inputStream.hasNext());
for(count = 0; inputStream.hasNext() ; count++) {
    tabSetting = new PermissionSetTabSetting();
    String data = inputStream.next();
    String[] permissionSetTabValues = data.split(",");
    System.out.println("Line:" + data);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `List<PermissionSetTabSetting>` so you don't have to bother checking the size first? You could always translate it back to an array once it's populated if you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response mates,I tried using list but since i have to do Dml operation i.e., SaveResult [] which returns an array as default i couldn't parse the values from list to an array, So i went on with the array.Do u have any other suggestion ? -feel free to engage. I will try it and let u know. - Lokesh

Comment: use `List.toArray()`

Comment: No @Joakim. My code worked fine when i fixed the array size manually like PermissionSettabSetting[88] but i shouldn't do like that so i choose to have another loop to instantiate the size .....Check the solved answer marked by me. Thanks for the support . -Lokesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading from a text file, why not use [Java 7 Files.readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)? It stores all lines into a `List<String>` and then you can use the list size to instantiate the array, as ryburger said:

```
List<String> data = Files.readAllLines(new File("E:\\" + filename).toPath());
PermissionSetTabSetting[] record = new PermissionSetTabSetting[data.size()];
```

Comment: As a small note, instead of using `File` you can use `Path` directly. E.g. `Paths.get("E:\\", filename)`.

Comment: Its pretty clean and nice .Thanks @eera. It worked fine for me. 

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the first scanner to make the array size for the second one, just use a List. Then when you need the size for some other reason, when the list is full you can do `listName.size()`.

Comment: Please refer to the above comment @ryburger. Thanks for the response, Any suggestions or ideas are welcome

Comment: @Lokesh Did you try using Arrays.asList(listName)?

Comment: Thank u for your suggestion mate ...Appreciate it much ✌